# Property 'cache' does not exist issue in nodejs project with using mogoose and recachegoose

Tags: mongoose

```
Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Query<any[], any, {}, any>'. Did you mean 'catch'?
```

This can be simply said that Query.cache() is not a function.

#### Versions:

```
"mongoose": "^7.0.0",
"recachegoose": "^9.2.1",
```

### code

(Using Typescript)

**middleware.ts**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import cachegoose from 'recachegoose';

cachegoose(mongoose, {
  engine: 'memory'
});
```

**fetch.ts**

```
results = await model.find({ key: queries.id }).cache(20);
```

#### ERROR:

```
const tempModel: mongoose.Model<any> = await this.model("collectionName");
results = await tempModel.find({ key: queries.id }).cache(20);
                                                   ^^^^^
Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Query<any[], any, {}, any>'. Did you mean 'catch'?
```

I used

```
mongoose": "5.10.9
```

and

```
recachegoose": "^8.1.0"
```

there was not issues and working well,

after that is upgrade mongoose 6.0.0
then got above issue , and I checked with

```
recachegoose": "^9.2.1"
```

error not fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

Our final decision is in Mongoose version upgrade there were modifications done for the model registration part.Older mongoose versions when we register in connection.model, mongoose register that model on their mongoose.model itself. But in updated versions if when we use the connection. model that model only registers for the connection. The issue comes from Recachegoose because the Recachegoose npm package checked models only from Mongoose models.
our solution is we forcefully register our models in connection. model and mongoose. model.

- model = connection.model(collectionName, Schema);
- mongoose.model(model.modelName, model.schema);